# Gateway Laptop Won't Boot From USB Drive

Tags: boot, usb, laptop, drive, gateway

Well it kinda boots, but right when it should reach the screen to ask to install or try, I only get a black screen. I tried to put a HDD with Ubuntu on it in my laptop, it boots fine until it reaches the grub menu, then I get the black screen, I can no longer use the laptop, it won't boot to windows due to a hardware change, but it used to. The laptop's model number is: KAYF0. Please help, any would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if possible I always recommend a dvd live disk, as the read speeds on a usb vary and creating a working bootable one is a true pain. Try using a dvd if possible and see if that makes a difference. If it doesn't, try pressing tab as soon as you get the black/purple/whatever screen when it first boots and go down to "install ubuntu", that will boot straight into the installer and I've found that it avoids some of the issues with graphics/incompatibilities in the live session

Comment: I don't know if that would help, I have ubuntu completely installed on another HDD, but that won't give me anything but black after grub.

Comment: is it 32 or 64 bit cpu?

Comment: According to windows's website, its a 64 bit pc

Comment: But I have both 32 and 64 bit boot drives, the only difference is I can hear ubuntu noises when I push the left and right arrow keys.

Comment: try using a 32 bit usb just in case, I know it seems hit or miss but it might be a 32 bit pc. Also, is this the surface/surface pro you are talking about?

Comment: Its an older Windows 7 pc. Also I think this is the laptop http://www.amazon.com/Gateway-NV7802u-17-3-Inch-Black-Laptop/dp/B002QQ1WM6.

Comment: what graphics card?

Comment: Intel GMA 4500MHD

Comment: just a hunch, try removing it and if you can boot then install the correct drivers for it

Comment: it sounds like a driver issue and that it is able to boot but just not sending it's display output TO the display

Comment: How do I remove it?

Comment: open the bottom of the computer, it'll be the largest visible board (probably)

Comment: approximately square, like an extended ram module

Comment: i think its integrated, i wouldnt know where to start

Comment: really sounds like drivers. Try downloading and loading onto usb Linux Mint, they seem to have the best drivers out of box. see if that works for you, or even try loading something like archlinux to see if IT recognizes your display

Comment: Can you link me to those websites?

Comment: archlinux.org and linuxmint.com

Comment: thankfully most of the sites just use the name of their distro (cough :microsoft: cough)

Comment: Lol okay thanks for the help ill try to see if they work, if not, I'll be back

Comment: be back if it does work too so I can know!

Comment: What is the best version of Linux Mint to download?

Comment: Cinnamon, MATE, KDE, or kfce?

Comment: I use kde as my desktop environment, but cinnamon is better for low end systems, really just look at screenshots and reviews and see what you like, you can just install another whenever you like. I use kde because it offers a TON of customization options, but cinnamon is a lot easier to use out of the box, kde really requires a lot of user customization to be really usable. Also, it depends whether you like kde apps or gnome based apps. Cinnamon is gnome 3 while mate is gnome 2

Comment: and...i'd really truly only use xfce on a really low powered netbook or a server I never use, it looks like it came straight from the 1990s, with no real ways to change it :P

Comment: I saw, and I started cinnamon, its downloading now, is there a way to get java on either OS? Same with wine?

Comment: very easy to install, I believe that mint has java preinstalled, and it might have wine as well but if not you can literally just apt-get it

Comment: same as ubuntu?

Comment: it's a fork so it uses the same packages, repos, think of it as ubuntu for those who don't care whether the programs they're using are proprietary or not :) (plus it has some awesome skins IMNSHO)

Comment: Sounds nice, as long as i can play mc and do my channel stuff, im happy

Comment: I made a linux mint boot drive and everything started until it reached the same spot as where ubuntu went black, I got the exact same resukts, I got windows running again, tho so im not as urgent.

Comment: I'm really wondering if it's a hardware issue at this point

Comment: Yeah. . .Its weird and at first I gave me the message cpu 0 has frozen for 22 seconds and it would repeat the message nonstop until windows worked agian

Comment: Can I clean any of these comments up?

Comment: I think there really is a lot of info in them about basically what worked and what didn't, leave them up until someone answers and it works, ok?